# Regex to match numbers followed by a specific character

Tags: regex, preg-match

I am so sorry, I know this is a simple question, which is not appropriate here, but I am terrible in `regex`.

I use `preg_match` with a pattern of (numbers A) to match the following replaces with the substrings

```
2A -> <i>2A</i>
100 A -> <i>100 A</i>
84.55A -> <i>84.55A</i>
92.1 A -> <i>92.1 A</i>
```

- The numbers can be separated from the character or not
- The numbers can be decimal
- The letter should not be the begging of a word (not matching `4 All`;
  in fact, `A` should be followed by a space or period or linebreak)

My problem is to apply `OR` conditions to match a character which may exist or not to have a single match to be replaced as

```
$str = preg_replace($pattern, '<i>$1</i>', $str);
```

Comment: So, what is the expected output for `2A,100 A,84.55A,92.1 A`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I want to make the match `italic`.

Comment: See [`\b\d*\.?\d+\s*A\b`](https://regex101.com/r/MjO7ql/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can't believe it. The world of regex is like a magic to me, which makes me look so stupid. THANKS!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest

```
'~\b(?<![\d.])\d*\.?\d+\s*A\b~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MjO7ql/3). Replace with `'<i>$0</i>'` where the `$0` is the backreference to the whole match.

**Details**:

- `\b` - leading [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html)
- `(?<![\d.])` - a [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that fails the match if there is a dot or digit before the current location (NOTE: this  is added to avoid matching `33.333.4444 A` like strings, just remove if not necessary)
- `\d*\.?\d+` - a usual simplified float/int value regex (0+ digits, an optional `.` and 1+ digits) (NOTE: if you need a more sophisticated regex for this, see [*Matching Floating Point Numbers with a Regular Expression*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html))
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `A\b` - a whole word `A` (here, `\b` is a trailing word boundary).